# SFP+ to 10GbE RJ45

Tags: networking, 10gbethernet, sfp

We have Intel x520 10Gb SFP+ network adapter.

We have RJ45 network cables to connect to a 10GbE network.

We have looked into direct attach cables and transceivers but we are struggling to find a way to get the two connected up.

Is there any way to establish this connectivity?

Comment: What port do you have where you want to connect Intel x520 10Gb SFP+ card?

Comment: We have RJ45 cables to connect to a 10GbE network.

Comment: If cables isn't long you can change them to sfp+ sfp+ copper cables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFP+ is a slot designed primerally for fiber optic transciver modules. It is also possible to directly connect two SFP+ devices using a "SFP+ Direct attatch" cable.

Unfortunately 10GBASE-T transcievers for SFP+ slots are not readilly available. I've seen one vendor that claims to offer them but no indication of price was given. Also the distance was limited to 30m due to power limitations.

There are also media converters available in seperate boxes with their own power supplied that can interconnect between 10GBASE-T and fiber or SFP+ DA but iirc the prices were eye-watering and it means a messy extra box.

If you already have the cabling and switches in place for 10GBASE-T then your best option is almost certainly to buy a different network card that supports 10GBASE-T (e.g the Intel x520-T2 seems to be the 10GBASE-T equivilent of your card).

If your switches have SFP+ ports available then you could use those to connect to your NIC over either a SFP+ direct attatch cable or a pair of transcivers and a fiber cable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run an SFP+ card into 10GbaseT switch ports, you'd need a media converter if such exist and it would probably be cheaper to bin the X520s

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to find sfp+ module with rj45 female connector for copper 6A category cables. But we usually use sfp+ to sfp+ copper path cables when needed length is less 10 metres. It's low cost solution. Otherwise we use optical cable with optical transceiver. It gives less errors count. Copper cable must be 6A category with length no more 60 metres.

Answer (score 0):

Sfp is also one of a media converter if you are having a Sfp port in your device connect with the help of patch card and also check Sfp capacity and device capacity and another think 2 types of Sfp is are available check your port first 
No need to use copper you may pass 1 gig++ bandwidth.